# Procedure isn't doing anything

Tags: mysql, procedure

Please, could somebody help me modify my mysql code below?

It is not affecting rows as I would like. :/ I am a beginner.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS category$$


CREATE PROCEDURE category()
BEGIN
 DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 877;
 DECLARE prd INT;



 WHILE count < 1040 DO

   select product_id into prd from xxx_hikashop_product 
   where (replace(product_name, 'Model ', '') = count);

   insert into xxx_hikashop_product_category 
   (product_category_id, category_id, product_id, ordering)
   VALUES
   (1445+count, 33, prd, count);


   SET count = count + 1;
 END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

PRINTED ERROR:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near    
'select product_id from elody_hikashop_product where replace(product_alias, 
'mode' at line 7
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to call procedure :D :D

Comment: From what I can tell, you're comparing the result of function replace, which is a VARCHAR, with variable count, which is an INT.

Comment: The error message says `.... select product_id from elody_hikashop_product where replace(product_alias, 'mode' ` but there is no a such line in a code you have shown us in the question. Do you really run/compile tthe procedure from the question ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the product_alias field has the form "Model 888" and your trying to extract the numeric value, and compare it with count.  You will need to convert the resulting string to a number, using:

```
select product_id into prd from xxx_hikashop_product
where (convert(replace(product_name, 'Model ', ''), UNSIGNED) = count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem was that I forgot to call procedure :D Thank you

Filip